# How to deserialize opencv image, sent from c++ to python 3?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

Im working on a python3 app where I need to create an openCV image from data which was serialized by a C++ app and stored in a protobuf message.
I only have access to the struct which contain the following data :

```
message Image {
    uint32          rows            =1;
    uint32          cols            =2;
    int32           elemType        =3; //openCV type (ex: CV_8U)
    int32           elemSize        =4;
    bytes           data            =5;
}
```

I have already tried to do this, passing through numpy to first create an array, but I think Im doing wrong...

Here is some code, where `img` is the struct I mentionned previously :

```py
def DeserializeImage(self, img):
    # We have to parse the OpenCV elem type because we first build a numpy array from serialized data
    numpyType = self.ParseOpenCVType(img.elemType)
    data = np.frombuffer(img.data, dtype=numpyType)
    data = data.reshape(img.rows, img.cols)

    # If we use a float, the range is probably between 0 and 1
    if data.dtype == np.float32:
        data = 255 * data

    cv2.imwrite('color_img.png', data)

    # SHOW FOR TESTS
    cv2.imshow('Color image', data)
    cv2.waitKey(int(1000/23))

def ParseOpenCVType(self, id):
    # Rough parsing of OpenCV elem type, need to be improved
    try:
        openCVType = [name for name in dir(cv2) if name.startswith("CV_") and getattr(cv2, name) == id][0]

        if openCVType.endswith("32F"):
            numpyType = np.float32
        elif openCVType.endswith("8U"):
            numpyType = np.uint8
        else:
            raise TypeError(openCVType)
    except TypeError:
        print('Exception raised: Unknow numpy type !')
        raise

    return numpyType
```

I want to skip the weird parsing which is done here, but how ? I dont know...
(Im new to python, openCV and stackoverflow, so be kind please ^^)

Comment: UP !!

Someone can help me ? I didnt found anything working yet...